# Stop floating sticky sidebar div at footer (almost working)

Tags: jquery, sticky

I want to get it so the last div on my sidebar stays sticky when the page scrolls, but stops at the footer. I have it almost working with an [online tutorial](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/smart-floating-banners/), but the calculation messes up when disqus comments load and it only goes to a certain point.

Here's a working version http://jsfiddle.net/k56yR/1/, but Is there an easy way to do something like calculate the footer height and then tell it to stop scrolling that far from the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think your problem is that your `$('#footer').offset().top` value changes after your disqus comments load. So you need to update `footerTop` (and `limit` based on the new `footerTop` value) after your comments load or every time your event fires.

something like:

```
$(function(){ // document ready
   if ($('#sticky').length) { // make sure "#sticky" element exists
      var el = $('#sticky');
      var stickyTop = $('#sticky').offset().top; // returns number
      var stickyHeight = $('#sticky').height();

      $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
          var limit = $('#footer').offset().top - stickyHeight - 20;

          var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

          if (stickyTop < windowTop){
             el.css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0 });
          }
          else {
             el.css('position','static');
          }

          if (limit < windowTop) {
          var diff = limit - windowTop;
          el.css({top: diff});
          }
        });
   }
});
```

As with most of the cases, there is a jQuery plugin for this, as [julianm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/537135/julianm) pointed out in his comment, available [here](https://github.com/AndrewHenderson/jSticky). It also supports a stopper value, to stop the sticky box at any desired position.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost working now. Thought it was, but with different browsers it ignores the limit and scrolls past the footer. Seems to work once when you either clear the cache or refresh the page, then doesn't for each repeat view. Any ideas?

Here's an example on the site http://thecomeupbmx.net/videos/red-bull-empire-of-dirt-practice-edit/ (it's not mine, i just work on it)

Comment: I'd need some kind of test case for this that always fails. It might be the browsers caching the old js but I can't reproduce this.

Comment: This jQuery plugin https://github.com/AndrewHenderson/jSticky (I saw it in one of the comments of the previous example provided by Mike Jonas) did exactly what I was looking for. It supports a stopper value (can be a class, ID or even a numeric value) to stop the sticky box at any desired position.