# sticky sidebar doesn't stop before footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem when i build my blog, there something i want to know how to make my sidebar widget sticky and stop scroll before #footer

How do I make it stop before footer?
My widget is going through my footer and I really appreciate if someone can help me, and for sure other people have the same question.

this a script :

```js
<script>
// Sticky widget by Bloggersentral.com
// Tutorial at http://www.bloggersentral.com/2013/04/how-to-make-any-widget-sticky.html 
// Free to use or share, but please keep this notice intact.
//<![CDATA[
bs_makeSticky("YOUR_WIDGET_ID"); // enter your widget ID here
function bs_makeSticky(elem) {
    var bs_sticky = document.getElementById(elem);
    var scrollee = document.createElement("div");
    bs_sticky.parentNode.insertBefore(scrollee, bs_sticky);
    var width = bs_sticky.offsetWidth;
    var iniClass = bs_sticky.className + ' bs_sticky';
    window.addEventListener('scroll', bs_sticking, false);
    function bs_sticking() {
        var rect = scrollee.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (rect.top < 0) {
            bs_sticky.className = iniClass + ' bs_sticking';
            bs_sticky.style.width = width + "px";
        } else {
            bs_sticky.className = iniClass;
        }
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.bs_sticking {background:#f2f2f2 !important; position:fixed !important; top:0; z-index:9999; box-shadow:0px 10px 4px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); margin-top: 0; position:relative\9 !important;}
</style>
```

Q : How do I make it stop before footer?

Comment: @reinder .. if you dont mind, you can inspect my blog element http://christcay.blogspot.co.id/, there is a #sidebar with id HTML3 (PROFIL STMIK BUMI GORA) thats widget sidebar i want to stop before #footer with id HTML4 (CHRISTIANTO D,WIBOWO)..

Thanks A Lot

Comment: @reinder .. yes it was sticky, but when i or you scroll it, the sticky #right sidebar it through to my #footer, i need your help (please..please please) to stop thats sticky before my #footer, so thats sticky doesn't close my #footer, i was try to put variabel limit to stop that 
with this : 
var limit = bs_sticky ('#HTML4').offset().top - stickyHeight - 20;
but its doesn't work ( i use google chrome browser to test it)
Thanks A lot.

Comment: I think, nothing is impossible in java, javascript ... etc. but it turned out there is "impossible" in java, javascrpt, etc.
please MASTER CODES give me some advise, how to make my float/sticky right sidebar doesn't close throught  to my footer at end of page, i dont undertand yet how technically code languages to said that, in th fact thats float/sticky  close throught  to my footer .. just want it stop float/sticky before my footer, please please please, i am begging you MASTERS CODES.....
i was try a many way as beginner in coding, but it always mess up... please. Thanks

Comment: @reinder 
sorry big bro, no offense ...
I just meant to convey the message and convince myself as a beginner, " that nothing is impossible learning code ...  and believe its always a way out"
dont go away, please help me

Comment: I found the answer in this forum as well (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669175/stop-floating-sticky-sidebar-div-at-footer-almost-working), after i replace all the existing code in the problems above, but its not running well too.  The problem is in jquery,  apparently after allotment Jquery I separate, all the code is running smoothly. At issue in my blog, one Jquery for Sticky Sidebar widget  (I place it precisely below the <head> and not above the </ head>), one more for  Jquery Slider on the homepage, and finally its running well.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved now, solution is in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669175/stop-floating-sticky-sidebar-div-at-footer-almost-working/40832257#40832257), However, it also will not be quite perfect, I just add Jquery just below the  for this sticky sidebar  widget, and one more Jquery for image slider on the homepage, and eventually all went well.